# Pivot a column in Dataframe which is having multiple values for the pivoted columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a dataframe as shown below.

```
+------+-------------+------+-----+
|NUM_ID|         TIME|SIGNAL|VALUE|
+------+-------------+------+-----+
|XXXX01|1571634079547|  SIG1|78860|
|XXXX01|1571634090000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634042000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634050000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634050000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634066000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634074000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634090000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634088000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634040000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634048000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634056000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634088000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634072000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634080000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634088000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634094000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634038000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634046000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634054000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634062000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634070000|  SIG1|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634078000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634092000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634036000|  SIG2|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634044000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634052000|  SIG3|25.73|
|XXXX03|1571634060000|  SIG3|25.73|
+------+-------------+------+-----+
```

I want to take each SIGx as a new column and corresponding VALUE as rows for each SIGx from existing column SIGNAL.

The output should be as shown below.

```
+------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
|NUM_ID|         TIME| SIG1| SIG2| SIG3|
+------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
|XXXX01|1571634079547|78860| null| null|
|XXXX01|1571634090000|25.73| null|25.73|
|XXXX01|1571634042000|25.73| null| null|
|XXXX01|1571634050000|25.73|25.73| null|
|XXXX01|1571634066000| null|25.73| null|
|XXXX01|1571634074000| null|25.73| null|
|XXXX02|1571634088000|25.73|25.73|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634040000|25.73| null| null|
|XXXX02|1571634048000|25.73| null| null|
|XXXX02|1571634056000|25.73| null| null|
|XXXX02|1571634072000| null|25.73| null|
|XXXX02|1571634080000| null|25.73| null|
|XXXX02|1571634094000| null| null|25.73|
|XXXX02|1571634038000| null| null|25.73|
|
|
|
+------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

The VALUE for SIGx with same TIME should be in same row.

Is there any way to achieve this?
I tried with pivot function but not working as expected for pivoted columns having multiple values.

Any leads appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupBy` `"NUM_ID"` and `"TIME"` and `pivot` with `"SIGNAL"` and get the first value from `"VALUE"` as below.

```
df.groupBy("NUM_ID", "TIME")
  .pivot("SIGNAL")
  .agg(first("VALUE"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but getting an error as ```org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: "VALUE" is not a numeric column. Aggregation function can only be applied on a numeric column.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset$$anonfun$3.apply(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:103```
The column VALUE is of string type.
I have values of DOUBLE and BIGINT  in the VALUE column, so that casting to a particular type is also not possible.-@Shankar Koirala

Comment: Can you provide the schema of dataframe?

Comment: -```scala> DF.printSchema
root
 |-- NUM_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SIGNAL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VALUE: string (nullable = true)```

Comment: I tried without agg as ```df.groupBy("NUM_ID", "TIME")
  .pivot("SIGNAL")``` But how can we see the data  after execution of pivot function. show function will not work as it is not a member of  **RelationalGroupedDataset**.- @Shankar Koirala

Comment: it should always follow group by with some aggregation function as .agg()